# Run MongoDB server as a service (detached from terminal)?

Tags: service, mongodb

When I start the MongoDB server (mongod) from terminal it keeps that tab open. How do I go about running it as a service?

I'm on OSX Lion.

I like how the rails server script has a -d option to detach it from terminal.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This is built into `mongod`, much like it is in the rails server. Instead of `-d` you'll need to use `--fork` and you'll probably want to specify `--logpath /path-to/logfile --logappend` as well, so that your output will be logged and will keep any previous logs.

See [the docs on starting and stopping Mongo](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Starting+and+Stopping+Mongo#StartingandStoppingMongo-RunningasaDaemon) for more information.

Comment: Or specify a config file which includes the `fork = true` line, then start mongod as `mongod --config mongo.conf`.

Comment: As of 2.4.4 building from source (for SSL support) do not install control script. One can create script with the help of this post (http://www.ewanleith.com/blog/15/mongodb-initd-script) and the provided configurations.

Comment: As @JamesChen said its easier adding in the configuration under the parameter `processManagement:` add `fork: true`

Answer (score 0):

To set up MongoDB to run as a background service, check out the [mongo-installer](https://github.com/paulrosania/mongo-installer) package for OS X 10.5+ or the [MongoDB-OSX-Launchctl](https://github.com/AndreiRailean/MongoDB-OSX-Launchctl) scripts.